# Проблема с JQUERY DROPDOWN MOBILE MENU

Tags: jquery, dropdown

JQUERY DROPDOWN MOBILE MENU. Не переходит по ссылкам в выпадающем меню и в элементе у которого есть выпадающий лист:

```
if ($('.mobileMenu').length > 0) {
        $('.mobileMenu').on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('.mainnav > ul').slideToggle('slow');
        });
        if ($(window).width() < 768)
        {
            $(".has-menu-items a").on('click', function() {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
                $(this).parent().children('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');
                return false;
            });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(".has-menu-items a")` добавь класс `parent` для родительского `a` т.е. будет так `$(".has-menu-items a.parent")`. У тебя переход не срабатывает потому что когда происходит событие `$(".has-menu-items a")` ты делаешь `return false;` что означает все `a href` внутри `has-menu-items` будут получать при клике `return false;`

Comment: Спасибо,элементы сработали.А если в двух родителях,тоже стоят ссылки,при первом клике открыть выпадающий лист и во втором на свою же ссылку перейти

Comment: @FaridValiyev вам тогда надо добавить проверку, если у родительского `a` есть элементы, то, добавлять класс `parent`. А если нет `child` элементов, то, просто добавьте `non-child-parent` (ну, это так, на будущее). И таким способом у вас должна работать клик по родительской ссылке без `child` элементов.

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли, без чайлд элементов работают, проблема в выпадающем,на самом и в выпадающем листе есть ссылка, например в самом ссылка на все проекты, а  в выпадающем листе ссылка на текущие проекты и завершенные

Comment: @FaridValiyev а, ну тогда тоже самое как для родительского, добавляете для **текущие проекты и завершенные** класс `parent`

Comment: все исправил,заработало.Спасибо большое